# Logrotate - Is there a conflict?

Tags: logrotate

`/etc/logrotate.d/auth.conf` is somnething I created manually. But there is a entry for `/var/log/auth.log` in `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` as well.

Is there  a conflict?

Do I have to remove `auth.log` entry from `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`? I'm trying to manage `auth.conf` using puppet but I don't want to manage `rsyslog` using puppet yet.

/etc/logrotate.d/auth.conf content:

```
/var/log/auth.log {
  daily
  rotate 5
  compress
  create 0644 root adm
}
```

/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog content:

```
/var/log/syslog
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog reload > /dev/null
        endscript
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
        rotate 4
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog reload > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no conflict, but there is a problem.  Your config will cause auth.log to be rotated daily, without notifying rsyslog.  As a consequence, rsyslog will keep writing to a deleted file for the remainder of the week, unless one of the rsyslog logs needs rotating sooner.

Comment: so I have to add `postrotate` and notify `rsyslog` in `auth.conf` right?

Comment: Correct, but compare your config to the original, which has eg. delaycompress.  Also, I'm not an avid user of logrotate, I prefer programs, like rsyslog, to handle their own rotation.  It's quite simple to have rsyslog start a  new log every day.